# Name of task - splitting up complex sentences?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I've go a question about the name of an NLP task - Splitting up a complex sentence into simple ones.
For example, if I have this sentence:

"Input t on the username input box and password input box."

I'd like to split this sentence into simpler sentences:

"Input t on the username input box"
"Input t on the password input box"

What would this problem be called? I've tried clause extraction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320015/how-to-split-an-nlp-parse-tree-to-clauses-independent-and-subordinate) but I don't want clauses, but rather, fully formed sentences. I've also tried 'sentence simplification' but it exceeds what I'm trying to do, with its lexical simplification and all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is the name used by everyone but, for example, in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.01035 they call it split-and-rephrase (in several other papers this term is used too).