# How to create parse tree for generalized way to split unique sentences by subordinate or independent clauses?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have been looking for a way to take a sentence and split it into clauses. So far I have found this example online: [How to split an NLP parse tree to clauses (independent and subordinate)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320015/how-to-split-an-nlp-parse-tree-to-clauses-independent-and-subordinate)

However, the parse tree is given in this example. How can I create one for any sentence? I would like to find out how to create the parse tree that is used for the solution's input in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html), [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#dependency-parse), [stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/depparse.html) to perform this task.